# pandas dataframe having duplicate values in column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

this is just a sample of some csv i have.

```
s.no  names   company_position
 1    A       Technical Recruiter
 2    B       Human Resource
 3    B       Corporate Trainer
 4    C       Recruiter
 5    C       English Teacher
```

**OUTPUT I WANT**

```
s.no   names   company_position     company_position_1
 1     A       Technical Recruiter   NAN
 2     B       Human Resource        Corporate Trainer
 3     C       Recruiter             English Teacher
```

I have same values in name column but having different values in company_position column.I want to make another column where i can put =duplicate values of name column into another column describe as company_position_1

Comment: Hi, can you please format your answer? It helps in readability , Kindly check out this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: What did you already do? What is the problem you are facing? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['A','Technical Recruiter'], ['B', 'HR Consultant','NAFTA'], \
    ['C', 'Executive Search Consultant Senior Technology Recruiter'], \
   ['D', 'Recruiter / HR Coordinator']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Current_position', 'Region'], index = 
[1,2,3,4])
print(df)
```

output will be

Name                                   Current_position Region

1    A                                Technical Recruiter   None

2    B                                      HR Consultant  NAFTA

3    C  Executive Search Consultant Senior Technology ...   None

4    D                         Recruiter / HR Coordinator   None

Comment: hello,can you please see my desire output.i have modified my problem

Answer (score 0):

## import pandas library

```
import pandas as pd
```

## creating a list

```
data = [['A','Technical Recruiter'], ['B', 'HR Consultant','corporate Trainer'], \
    ['C', 'Recruiter','English Teacher']]
```

## creating a dataframe from list by adding column names and index

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Company_position','company_position1'],\ 
    index = [1,2,3])
print(df)
```